# Limiting words in textarea with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been trying to limit words in text area using AngularJS.
So far I have tried this

#### Textarea HTML

```
<textarea ng-model="man_abs" style="height: 100px;" id="manuscriptabstract" name="manuscriptabstract" placeholder="Maximum 250 Words" class="form-control" ng-change="wordCount()" required=""></textarea>
<span class="help-block">{{251 - man_abs.split(' ').length}} words left</span>
```

#### AngularJS script

```
$scope.wordCount = function() {
    if ($scope.man_abs != undefined) {
        var key_length = $scope.man_abs.split(' ').length;
        if (key_length >= 251) {
           $scope.man_abs = $scope.man_abs.substring(0, $scope.man_abs.lastIndexOf(" "));
           alert("You are allowed to enter only 250 words in this field");
        }
    }
}
```

I seems to work fine ,but when I  copy paste a paragraph more than 250 words ,it is not working as expected.

I have tried preventDefault() method and it is not working.
I need to make sure that user should not be able to type more than 250 words, If Copy pasted , after 250th word the sentence have to be removed..

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `maxlength="250"`

Comment: It actually limits characters , not words. I have tried that , What I am trying to do is limit the words.

Comment: Sorry - i didn't notice you're restricting words and not characters.

Comment: No Problem..at all

Comment: @SibiRaj it is the problem the novice developer. They don't accept the solution.If any of the below solution is not working and you have found a different solution which is working then post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try to limit the words with a directive like so:

```
.directive('myCheck', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('keyup', function (e) {
                  console.log(this.value);
                  var words = this.value.split(" ");
                  console.log("words are:",words.length)
                  var tmp = '';
                  if (words.length >5){
                    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
                      tmp += words[i] + ' ';
                    }
                    this.value = tmp;
                  } 
                });
            }
        }
});
```

### into HTML:

```
<input type="text" my-check> /*you can do it with textarea as well*/
```

### plunker example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/7EeUbu1d96vCCQhi8g19?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, you can add one vote if you find this solution  usefull!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. `ng-click = wordCount()`
2. Use angular watch `$watch` to see the changes.

> But I would recommend you to go with `ng-click` option. As it's much easy and won't create load / stress over page as $watch don't lets page rest.

Example:

`<textarea ng-model="man_abs" style="height: 100px;" id="manuscriptabstract" name="manuscriptabstract" placeholder="Maximum 250 Words" class="form-control" ng-change="wordCount()" ng-click="wordCount()" required=""></textarea>`

**In controller**

`$scope.wordCount = function() {
    if ($scope.man_abs != undefined) {
        var key_length = $scope.man_abs.split(' ').length;
        if (key_length >= 251) {
           var trimmedString = $scope.man_abs.substring(0, 250);
           $scope.man_abs = trimmedString;
           alert("You are allowed to enter only 250 words in this field");
        }
    }
}`

Comment: but how to trim the sentence ,there exists my problem.

Comment: it should work now, replace 250 in code according to your requirement

Comment: but trimming i s tricky, When I copy pase ,Some thing happens , during copy pase ,it randomly trims ,not after 250 word

Comment: >no index is given from 0th index to 250th index would only be trimmed. Code is tested can't just do things randomly

Comment: try adding extra space between each word, It happens at those case only, Sorry its my mistake that I haven't explained completely.else it works charm

Comment: so append this line `"$scope.man_abs".replace(" ", "");` after `$scope.man_abs = trimmedString;` line... You'll get your desired ..output

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator

```
.directive('maxwords', [function () {
  return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.maxwords = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        return (modelValue.match(/\S+/g) || []).length <= +attrs.maxwords;

      };
    }
  };
}])
```

and use it as:

```
  <textarea maxwords="30"/>
```

`error.maxwords` will be set foe validations just as usual validations.

Answer (score 0):

you should have to call your function on Paste event also like

```
<textarea ng-model="man_abs" style="height: 100px;" id="manuscriptabstract" name="manuscriptabstract" placeholder="Maximum 250 Words" class="form-control" ng-change="wordCount()" ng-paste="wordCount()" required=""></textarea>
<span class="help-block">{{251 - man_abs.split(' ').length}} words left</span>
```

Comment: Thanks I added ng-paste but I can be to paste after 250 word thats the problem

Comment: then do some math logic here on ng-paste event like this var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4); now if your sentence length exceed from 250 then subtring your sentence like above example

Answer (score 0):

You can use $watch to complete this task
Try this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/jigarb1992/awLp4bnk/

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <textarea ng-model="txt" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <span class="help-block">{{limit}} words left</span>
    </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.limit = 250;
    $scope.$watch("txt", function(newValue, lastValue){
     var words = $scope.txt.split(" ").length - 1;
    if(words > 250 ){
        $scope.txt = lastValue;
    }
    $scope.limit = 250 - words;
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome @sibiraj so you make my answer as best

Answer (score 0):

You can use Split and join methods of Array.

So below will work in your case

```
 $scope.wordCount = function() {
        if ( $scope.man_abs != undefined ) {
          var key = $scope.man_abs.split( ' ' );
            if ( key.length >= 251 ) {
            $scope.man_abs = key.splice( 0, 250 ).join( ' ' );
           alert( "You are allowed to enter only 250 words in this field" );
               }
                }
            }
```